# Dynamic url to load images from server using lazy list in android

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am new in programming.

I want to know that if i have a string,

```
String string = a,b,c,d,e;
```

I want to convert this string to something like this:

```
String[] aaa = new String{"a","b","c"}
```

and I want to do this in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
String string = "a,b,c,d,e";
String[] aaa = string.split("[,]+");
```